# Cassandra - Column family exists but is not visible via describe or OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm currently evaluating Cassandra for an upcoming project and am trying to get my head around the basics.

I have an issue where when creating a column family via the CQL Shell - the column family is created as usable however it does not appear when I issue a DESCRIBE command with the CLI tool or when looking at the Cluster via DataStax OpsCenter.

I've created the keyspace as such:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Testing
WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};
```

and defined the column family as:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable(
Id int PRIMARY KEY,
Name text,
OtherValue int
);
```

I can successfully insert and select data from SampleTable however it does not show up with a Describe command or in OpsCenter.

I can create a visible Column Family using the CLI command line, or the API in FluentCassandra but would like to use the CQL approach.

This is day one with Cassandra so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column families created with CQL3 do not show up when using the thrift API. See the following issues for more information:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4377
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4924

Comment: This is a nightmare. Im struggling to know if my data model is correct when I cant see what internal column families CQL3 is creating. Im really keen to use CQL3 but having this layer of abstraction that I cant look past is very unnerving.